# Как задать for для label JS?

Tags: javascript

Как задать `for=""` для `<label>` следующего формата. Чтобы каждый из `for=""` по мере своей вложенности
увеличивался подобным образом:

```html
<label for="link01">
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<label for="link02">
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<label for="link03">
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

У меня  есть отрывок такого кода, но не приложу ума как указать `for=""`:
`document.querySelectorAll('.jkef').forEach((item, index) => item.id = "link0" + (index + 1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если динамически создавать `label`, то вот так:

```js
const labels = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < labels; i++) {
    const label = document.createElement('label'),
        checkbox = document.createElement('input');

    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

    label.setAttribute('for', `link${i + 1}`);

    label.appendChild(checkbox);

    console.log(label);
}
```

С помощью метода `.setAttridute`.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const counter = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    
    label = document.createElement('label'),
    checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    
    label.textContent = `link${i + 1}`;
    label.setAttribute('for', `link${i + 1}`);
    
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.setAttribute('id', `link${i + 1}`);
    checkbox.setAttribute('name', `link${i + 1}`);
    
    document.getElementById("app").appendChild(checkbox);
    document.getElementById("app").appendChild(label);
    
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: это нужно сделать через `js`, а не вручную

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]